# String vs SecureString Performance in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to know the performance impact `SecureString` brings into the picture.

Which is faster? `String` or `SecureString`?

I want to use SecureString to fix some of the fortification issues in my project. Previously I was having Strings and now I'm changing the code to use SecureString at the same time I would like to know if this change would slow down the things in the processing engine?

Comment: "faster" in what context?

Comment: Considering they solve completely different problems I'd say you're comparing apples and monkeys, therefore it is irrelevant which one is faster. If you think you have a legitimate case where you can use either, and think speed is relevant, you must tells us about this case.

Comment: Ok let me be more specific about the issue, I want to use SecureString to fix some of the fortification issues in my project. Previously I was having Strings and now Im changing the code to use SecureString at the same time I would like to know if this change would slow up the things in the processing engine? Hope I am clear now

Comment: @Yaswanth -- Update your question, don't dump substantive details in the comments.

Comment: Are you sure you read and understood what [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) is supposed to be used for?

Comment: @roryap : Better answer the question(if u have any) as u have info now

Comment: @Yaswanth -- "better answer the question"?  Excuse me?  A little demanding isn't it?  Sorry pal, good luck though.

Comment: @roryap : Offended by your previous comment. sorry for that. Cheers for the day

Comment: @Yaswanth -- I don't have an answer for your question unfortunately because it's off topic (which is why I voted to close it).  The purpose of my comment above was only to instruct you as to the proper procedure for adding substantive clarifications to your question, i.e. in the body of the questions not in the comments.  My apologies: I often come across as brusque.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can schedule `SecureString` for programmatic garbage collecion (through its `IDisposable` interface), so memory management is slightly easier and that can come in handy when working with large strings.

However, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says it "tries to avoid" storing its content in plain text - so presumably, there are additional steps for encryption and decryption. It's also immutable, so you should avoid appending and removing characters one by one.

I don't think these factors can be considered crucial to your application's performance - you should use `SecureString` if you have a reason to do so, otherwise just stick with `string`.